# what is the meaning of fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:'s parameters?

Tags: objective-c

I am a freshman , and i have a problem on the of my study.

When i use the fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory: method ，i don't know what the Parameters's meaning after isDirectory.

I saw that the Parameters after isDirectory is always NO in many code, when they want to confirm the existence of a folder.The documentation said that "contains YES if path is a directory or if the final path element is a symbolic link that points to a directory".i think it should be set to YES.

This is my code:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isDir;
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"myDocPath" isDirectory:&isDir] == YES)
{
    NSLog(@"Directory is Exists!");
}
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Directory is not Exists!");
    }
```

Thanks for your help , and my english is very bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!  I hope you enjoy participating here.

[NSFileManager's `fileExistsAtPath: isDirectory:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a) takes a path (a NSString object) and the "`isDirectory:`" part is a BOOL ***address***  (of a BOOL variable you declared before calling this method), which means the method *tells you* if the file pointed to in the path is actually a folder (or directory), then it returns YES.

So if you call it via:

```
BOOL directoryBool;
BOOL doesSomethingExistHere = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: @"/etc" isDirectory: &directoryBool];
if(doesSomethingExistHere)
{
    NSLog( @"something exists at the path");
    if(directoryBool)
        NSLog( @"and it's a directory");
    else
        NSLog( @"it's a file, not a directory");
} else {
    NSLog( @"nothing exists at the path you specified");
}
```

You should see how the parameter works.

Comment: Thanks for your help! About your code ,I know i must set a BOOL pointer , not a BOOL variable after "isDirectory". I think if i want to confirm the exsistence of the folder rather than the file , i must set YES to directoryBool! But the directoryBool is NO.

Comment: You don't need to set `directoryBool` at any point. You pass the *address of* the `directoryBool` local variable to the method. The method dereferences that address in order to write into your variable, so that the information is available to your code. You are not telling the method anything about the path, you are requesting that it tell you about it. The method ignores the original value of the `BOOL` value at the address; it just writes there, it doesn't read it.

Comment: I edited my comment to clarify.  Hopefully it helps.  Thanks @Ken

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, that's fine, but so was your previous wording. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but my comment was directed to Neuman and his followup questions. Cheers.

Comment: @KenThomases,Thank you very much! I think i know where i am wrong